Fit Negative Binomial Mixed-Effects model with instrumental variables with R
How can I fit a Fixed-Effects Negative Binomial model with instrumental variables with R?
I have tried fixest package, but it only supports instrumental variables for OLS, not for negative binomial:
id   <- rep(seq(1, 10), each=5)
year <- rep(seq(2021, 2025), times=10)
df   <- data.frame(id=id, year=year)
df[["weight"]] <- rnorm(nrow(df), 100, 10)
df[["height"]] <- 2*df$weight + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5)
df[["count"]] <- rpois(nrow(df), df$id + df$height + 
                                         rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5))
mod <- fixest::fenegbin(count ~ 1 | id | height ~ weight, df)

Error in fixest::fenegbin(count ~ 1 | id | height ~ weight, df) : 
  The argument 'fml' cannot contain more than two parts separated by a
  pipe ('|'). IVs are available only for 'feols'.  
  The syntax is: DEP VAR ~ EXPL VARS | FIXED EFFECTS. 
  (No IVs allowed.)

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73982152/iv-regression-in-fixed-effect-models-with-diagnostics/75144897#75144897

This is much more appropriate for https://stats.StackExchange.com. Once you have a specific task unambiguously described on a theoretical level, then coding can begin.

In your simulation, where is the bit that makes the DV dependent on the id variable via a random intercept/effect. id doesn't seem to show up in the line that simulates the count (DV) variable.

@HuyPham I changed the example so that now we have individual heterogeneity in the outcome mean and so we need to control for it. Thanks.
